# lme4: "fit warnings: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients" - how to fix it?

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to run a HLM analysis in R that predicts "ranking" with the rest of the columns as predictors - I want to include interaction effects but I keep getting the warning message "fit warnings: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 2 columns / coefficients". There is no linear dependence between the predictors so I am wondering whether this is because all of the four predictors used for the interaction terms are binary coded. I already tried to solve the problem with factor() but it doesn't change anything.
The code is the following:

```r
version_3_test <- lmer(ranking ~ 1 + ac_fc + npdc_fc + 
    ed_fc + iks_fc + ac_fc:ed_fc + ac_fc:iks_fc + 
    npdc_fc:ed_fc + npdc_fc:iks_fc + bu_ed_fc +
    nat_ed_fc + eng_ed_fc + it_ind_fc + ph_ind_fc + 
    eng_ind_fc + work + age + 
     (1 + ac_fc + npdc_fc + ed_fc + iks_fc| id_ind), 
    data = df_finaldata, REML = FALSE)
summary(version_3_test)
```

ac_fc, npdc_fc, iks_fc, ed_fc are factor-variables - each with two levels.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or what else could be the reason for the warning?

I tried interaction terms with other predictors that are not binary coded and this worked.

Comment: Check the data of those factor variables, it usually means there is not enough data per level in those variables to run an estimation of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There are almost certainly **multi**collinear columns in your model matrix.

If the four variables `ac_fc`, `npdc_fc`, `ed_fc`, `iks_fc` represent indicator variables for an exhaustive and mutually exclusive set of categories (i.e. if every observation comes from the set `{ac, npdc, ed, iks}`), then it's natural that these columns would be multicollinear (because their sum is always 1).

Another possibility is that you have interaction terms in your models where some combinations of levels are missing from the data (e.g. `A = {1, 2}`, `B = {1,2}`, you have `A*B` or `A:B` in  your model, but `A=2; B=2` never occurs in your data).

More generally,

```r
ff <- nobars(formula(version_3_test))
X <- model.matrix(ff, data = df_finaldata)
caret::findLinearCombos(X)
```

should diagnose exactly which set(s) of columns is/are multicollinear.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for your answer! - I checked  but it seems the problem is still there.. I am starting to question my approach, so I hope it is ok if I you give you  more context: I conducted a survey and asked each person to assess 16 scenarios (8 origin., each repl. with varying profiles (consisted of four attributes with 2 levels (high/low>  ac_fc, npdc_fc, ed_fc, iks_fc). I used an orthogonal factorial design to create the profiles. I still don't get how the inter. terms are dropped since I used the orth. design. I also checked regarding the combinations. I would appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Please edit your question to show `head(X)` (i.e., a few lines of the model matrix) and the output of `findLinearCombos` - please use a *text format* (i.e. cut-and-paste output into a code-formatted block, don't post screenshots)